# Wordpress Theme [Finale Elegance] Bugged Blog template

Tags: wordpress

I've been having issues with my blog template from a basic wordpress theme. 
The issuse is that the footer & the side bar are somehow still contained within the container div. I've gone through the code countless times now and i just cannot see what the issues is, all the closing tags are in the correct place but it still buggers up.

th website i'm creating is dev.pearlofbeauty.co.uk/blog

the code that i'm using for the blog template:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="column_680 m_bottom_20">  

    <?php

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args = array(

    'orderby'  => 'date',

    'order'    => 'DESC',

    'paged'    => $paged

    );


    query_posts($args);

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

    ?>

        <div class="column_210 m_top_55">

            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="blog_post_title"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

            <p class="blog_info">

                Date:       <span><?php the_time('F d,') ?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><?php the_time('Y') ?></span><br />

                Author:     <span><?php echo the_author_meta('nickname', get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?></span><br />

                Comments:   <span><?php comments_number() ?></span><br />

                Categories: <span><?php the_category(', '); ?></span>

            </p>

        </div><!--end column_210-->

        <div class="column_440 m_top_65 last">

            <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ){ the_post_thumbnail('blog'); }else{ ?>

                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/blank-blog.png">

            <?php } ?>

        </div><!--end column_440-->

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div class="post_content m_top_15">

            <p><?php content('50') ?></p>

            <a class="button read_more rounded" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>

        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>



        <?php endwhile; ?>



        <div class="more_post m_top_15 m_bottom_185">

            <?php echo pagination(); ?>

        </div>


    </div><!--end column_680-->



    <!--sidebar-->      

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <!-- End Sidebar -->


    <div class="clear"></div>

 </div><!--end container-->

 <div class="clear"></div>



     <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: It looks like the sidebar *should* still be in the container but the footer should *not*, is that correct?  If so, I would suspect that the markup in the sidebar is missing a closing div tag.

Comment: Just gone through all the sidebar php files. None of them are missing any closing tags :'(. I'm soo clueless haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the result of

```
<p><?php content('50') ?></p>
```

This part returns:

```
<h4 style="font-style: italic; color: #000000;">
    "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
</h4>
<h5 style="color: #000000;">
    "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
</h5>
<div style="color: #000000;">
    <div class="lc">
        <h2 class="what"></h2>
        <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of.
```

As you can see you're missing 2 closing div tags.

Comment: Oh wait i see it now. However the result code which is generated, i have no idea as to where i could access it! due to the PHP function you've mentioned, it calls the the data from post i think...

Comment: This function is located in the functions.php.